# how to gate Discrete Fourier Transform sample frequencies using numpy

Tags: python, matplotlib, signal-processing, fft

With the help of available tutorial and examples i have write down a code for the given data set provided to script through a text file "jai.txt".

```
1 13.5872
2 12.4938666667
3 14.1024
4 13.1434666667
5 13.1552
6 13.0570666667
7 13.2309333333
8 12.6170666667
9 12.4213333333
10 14.6373333333
11 11.8170666667
```

but this code is faulty generating blank graph. what changes should i made to correct this code.

```
from __future__ import division
from pylab import plot, ylim, xlim, show, xlabel, ylabel, grid
from numpy import linspace, loadtxt, ones, convolve
import numpy as numpy

data = loadtxt("jai.txt", float)

#def movingaverage(interval, window_size):
#    window= numpy.ones(int(window_size))/float(window_size)
#    return numpy.convolve(interval, window, 'same')

x = data[:,0]
y = data[:,1]

signal = y

fourier = numpy.fft.fft(signal)
n = signal.size
timestep = 1.0
freq = numpy.fft.fftfreq(n, d=timestep)

plot(x,freq,"k.")
#y_av = movingaverage(y, 3)
plot(x, freq,"r")
xlim(0,1)
xlabel("time.")
ylabel("mean")
grid(True)
show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first look at what you're plotting and you'd see the mistake.

```
print x.min(), x.max()
```

this returns '1.0 11.0'. So the problem is your xlim definition, as you set xlim(0,1) you will not see the plot as your x values go from 1 to 11. Comment out xlim and you'll see it.